# How do I plot the sum of two discrete time signal for different time index?

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, matlab-figure

How can I sum two discrete time signals with different time index, ie. given a first signal `x=[1 2 3 4 5]` at time indices `n1=-3:1`, and a second signal `y=[1 1 2 2 3]` at time indices `n2=0:4`.
I can't just add these two signals since their length differ. So far my code is:

```
n1=-3:1;
x=input('Enter the value of X:');
y=input('Enter the value of Y:');
subplot(3,1,1);
stem(n1,x);
grid on;
xlabel('Time index');
ylabel('Amplitude');
axis([-10 10 0 10]);
title('signal X');


n2=0:4;
subplot(3,1,2);
stem(n2,y);
grid on;
xlabel('Time index');
ylabel('Amplitude');
axis([-10 10 0 10]);
title('signal Y');
```

What should I do next? How can I proceed to add these two signals?

Comment: Do you imaging encountering a case like n1= 1 : 3 and n2 = .5 : 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

As a simplified approach, you could measure the size of your time domain and create a final variable `S` that has the same size. Also, create an index corrector `m` that enables us to use `n1` and `n2` as matrix indexes. Finally, sum `x` and `y` with their correct offset.

```
m=1-min([n1 n2])
S= zeros(1+max([n1 n2]) - min([n1 n2]),1)
S(m+[n1])= S(m+[n1])+x
S(m+[n2])= S(m+[n2])+y
stem([1:1:size(S,1)]-m,S)
```

You can extend this inductively to be compatible with a few more time series.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a new vector `n3` which is the union of `n1` and `n2`. Then, append `x` and `y` with zeros so their length match the length of `n3` and they are also correctly aligned.

```
n3 = min([n1 n2]):max([n1 n2]);
x = [x 0 0 0];
y = [0 0 0 y];
subplot(3, 1, 3);
stem(n3, x + y);
grid on;
xlabel('Time index');
ylabel('Amplitude');
axis([-10 10 0 10]);
title('signal X+Y');
```

The result is

[image: sum of signals]